# Back navigation ignores zxing barcode scanner

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using the zxing barcode scanner in my android application via the [IntentIntegrator](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) class. The scanner is started from my MainActivity. Once a barcode has been scanned, the result is passed back to MainActivity. If a barcode was successfully scanned then mainActivity redirects the user to a ConfirmSiteActivity.

If I press back on the ConfirmSiteActivity, then the barcode scanner is skipped, taking me directly to the MainActivity. Why is it skipped? And how can I allow back navigation to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Intent flags with which the Barcode Scanner is started. Try removing the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

Not knowing the exact scenario, it's difficult to judge, but I'd still suggest looking at your workflow again: are you sure the user really wants to scan a second time when pressing *back* in the confirmation dialog? Opening a scanner always is a bit time consuming and might have a negative influence on UX.

Comment: You've convinced me! 99% of the time I think the user would be trying to get back to the main menu, rather than scan a different QR code